# Use always https in web.xml not working

Tags: jakarta-ee, ssl, https, web.xml, deployment-descriptor

I am trying to use always https in my website. I have the following in my web.xml file:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>All access - GET and POST over SSL</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Common area - GET and POST</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method-omission>GET</http-method-omission>
        <http-method-omission>POST</http-method-omission>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <description/>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

However it doesn't work. Any idea of what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are explicitly allowing the `GET` and `POST` method to access your website in http with `<http-method-omission>` tag.

I think you meant :

```
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
```

But it would be better to just omit any declaration of HTTP method, as you surely want to force https for all of them.

Comment: Ok, now it uses https and port 8443, but I can't see my website with the browser.

Comment: I get an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Comment: I have two environments: 1) localhost where I have not done anything (I don't know how to configure certificates) and 2) my domain where I have supposedly installed a thawte certificate

Comment: What is your server configuration?